# Does Wing-IDE run in the background? If so, how slowly?

Tags: wing-ide

Does Wing-IDE run in the background? If so, how slowly?

I've been running a find-and-replace on basically a single line, for about 10 hours in the background, about 20000+ replaces have to be done.

Checking my CPU, and when Wing is not the active window, I'm getting reports that Wing is using 0%, usually and has jumps that get to about 0.2% at most.

But when I make it active, I'm getting 0.4% at a minimum, and hovering at 0.6% CPU...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Wing changes how it runs whether it's in the foreground or background, other than things like flashing the caret.  I'm fairly sure your search/replace is either done or not working at all or it would be at 100% CPU.  It could be a bug, and if so sending a bug report from the Help menu with the error log included might show us what went wrong.